# Building a low voltage disconnect w/ timer - need help with the timer

Tags: sketch, timers, voltage-level

I'm trying to build almost exactly this device:

http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/reuk-shop-low-voltage-disconnects-lvd/buy-reuk-programmable-low-voltage-disconnect-with-display/

It is a low voltage disconnect but has an interesting feature that requires the "cutoff" and "reconnect" voltages to be reached for 10 seconds before the connection is actually cut/re-connected to prevent premature status changes from voltage spikes/sags (Such as starting a car, or a motor with high start draw)

I need some example code that handles the timer portion. I can handle the "if this voltage is reached, disconnect the relay" (or transistor in the link I provided) part.

I need help making it "If this voltage has reached XX for 10 seconds then -do something-"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a function `voltageIsReached()`, here's a very simple way of doing it, which is OK if you don't have anything else to do in the mean time.

```
if (voltageIsReached()) {
    long end = millis() + 10000;   // 10s from now
    boolean voltageWasReachedFor10s = false;
    while (voltageIsReached()) {
        if (millis() >= end) {   
            voltageWasReachedFor10s = true;
            break;
        }
        delay(1);
    }
    if (voltageWasReachedFor10s) {
        // Do whatever you have to do
    }
}
```

If you *do* have something else to do while you're waiting for this 10s state, you will need to adapt this, but I hope it'll get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that has a static variable that keeps the previous time that the voltage has not been reached. That routine will read the voltage and reset the static variable to current time whenever the voltage has not been reached.

Such a routines can either return a logic value or a time value , depending on your implementation.